# trying to upload a file using ajax file uploaded but in corrupted php ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I am trying to upload a file using PHP ajax jquery file is uploading but in corrupted format how can i make it correct.

in my controller i am using

```
$product_image = $request->getParam("product_image");

            defined('PUBLIC_PATH') || define('PUBLIC_PATH', realpath(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))))));
            $filename = time() . rand(10000, 99999) . ".jpg";
            file_put_contents(PUBLIC_PATH . "/public_html/product_images/" . $filename, base64_decode($product_image));

$products->__set("product_image", $filename);

$data = array(
 "product_image" => $this->view->baseUrl() . "/product_images/" . $filename,
);
```

in ajax file

```
var p_image = $('#product_image').val();

$.ajax({


        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/api/products/add',
        data : {product_image:p_image},
                dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){

            if (response.data.product_id == true) {
            alert("Success");

                        alert(response.data.product_image);
```

Getting the content of uploaded file is

windows photo viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large.

please guide.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? How is it corrupt, do you get any errors?

Comment: No I am getting no error file is uploading into my folder, but when i opening that image there is nothing in it

Comment: windows photo viewer can"t open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large

Comment: `realpath(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))))` Whoa!

Comment: doesn't matter i jst need uploaded file do u have any idea

Answer (score 0):

open the photo file in a text editor like Notepad and you'll find out that it likely contains the string value of p_image.  More specifically, you're not actually uploading anything.  I'd recommend using something like jQuery's ajaxForm to upload with ajax.

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
         alert("Form is submitted"); 
});
```

Tutorial:

http://hayageek.com/ajax-file-upload-jquery/

Documentation:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/