# File Upload using ajax Zend Framework php

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

I am trying to upload a file using ajax zend framework i dont know how to do this. Below codes are working images are uploaded but i am getting nothing in image as image shows blank. Window photo viewer can't display the picture because the file is empty please guide

```
 public function addAction() {
        try {
            $request = $this->getRequest();
            //print_r($request);die;
            if (TRUE) {

                $product_image = $request->getParam("product_image");

 defined('PUBLIC_PATH') || define('PUBLIC_PATH', realpath(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))))));
                $filename = time() . rand(10000, 99999) . ".jpg";
                file_put_contents(PUBLIC_PATH . "/public_html/product_images/" . $filename, base64_decode($product_image));

 $productsMapper = new Application_Model_ProductsMapper();
                $products = new Application_Model_Products();


 $products->__set("product_image", $filename);

$product_id = $productsMapper->viewProduct($products);

                if ($product_id) {

                    $data = array(
                "product_image" => $this->view->baseUrl() . "/product_images/" . $filename,
);

 $meta = array(
                        "code" => 200,
                        "message" => "SUCCESS",
                        "success" => "true"
                    );


                    $arr = array(
                       "meta" => $meta,
                        "data" => $data
                    );
                } else {

                    $meta = array(
                        "code" => 401,
                        "message" => "Error while adding"
                    );
                    $arr = array(
                        "meta" => $meta
                    );
                }
            } else {
                $meta = array(
                    "code" => 411,
                    "message" => "Invalid Request"
                );
                $arr = array(
                    "meta" => $meta
                );
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {

            $meta = array(
                "code" => $e->getCode(),
                "message" => $e->getMessage()
            );

            $arr = array(
                "meta" => $meta
            );
        }
        $json = json_encode(@$arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        echo $json;
```

In my ajax file it is the code

```
$("#previewForm").click(function(){

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/api/products/add', 
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm currently working on a full AJAX image upload gallery with validations and response messages. The tutorial will be done in a few hours. Will post a link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [trying to upload a file using ajax file uploaded but in currupted php ajax jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666132/trying-to-upload-a-file-using-ajax-file-uploaded-but-in-currupted-php-ajax-jquer)

Comment: Alright Stainmir I'm waiting :)